# Create one select query for two tables with different columns

Tags: sql

I have two tables that contains different columns. I want to create a single query to fetch data from these two tables that where for a specific column for each table have `LIKE` condition with a php var named `$a`.

```
SELECT col_1 AS C FROM ekptes 
UNION
SELECT col_2 AS D FROM students
WHERE ekptes.surname OR 
students.eponimos 
LIKE  '%$a%'
```

The `UNION` operator doesn't work as I wrote the code. How I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below-

```
  SELECT col_1 AS C FROM ekptes  WHERE ekptes.surname LIKE  '%$a%'
  UNION
  SELECT col_2  FROM students WHERE students.eponimos  LIKE  '%$a%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for?

```
SELECT col_1 AS C FROM ekptes WHERE surname LIKE '%$a%'
UNION
SELECT col_2 AS D FROM students WHERE eponimos LIKE '%$a%'
```

You can use the repsective table's column search in it's `WHERE` clause.